# Grouping a group of people by their preferences

Tags: algorithms

I have following problem to solve:

I have a group of people which I have to split up into smaller groups. Some of them have preferences who they want to be in a group with and who they don't want to be in a group with. I have to determine wether it is possible to group them respecting their preferences and if so, I want to build the groups. So for example I have these people:

Tom: wants to be in a group with [Stephen, John], doesn't want to be in a group with [Jennifer]

Stephen: wants to be in a group with [John]

John: wants to be in a group with [Jennifer], doesn't want to be in a group with [Alice]

Jennifer: no preferences

Alice: wants to be in a group with [Tom]

The example above wouldn't work because Tom wants to be in a group with Stephen, Stephen wants to be in a group with John, John wants to be in a group with Jennifer, however Tom doesn't want to be in a group with Jennifer, so it couldn't be solved while respecting all preferences

Another example:

Tom: wants to be in a group with [Alice], doesn't want to be in a group with [Jennifer]

Stephen: no preferences

John: wants to be in a group with [Stephen], doesn't want to be in a group with [Tom]

Jennifer: wants to be in a group with [Stephen]

Alice: doesn't want to be in a group with [Jennifer]

This example would work with the following groups respecting all preferences: [Tom, Alice];   [John,Stephen,Jennifer]

I have been fiddling with this problem for some time now but I can't think of a solution and I also can't find any problem on the internet similar to mine although I am pretty sure that there is a popular problem similar to this one.

I still want to solve this myself, however I would be very happy if you could tell me if there is a popular problem similar to this one or if you could provide me with any hints for an approach that I could take to solve this.

Comment: How does this differ from standard assignment problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: @Evil thank you. I just read a bit about it and now I wonder if I have the right idea: I have a 2 dimensional matrix with both rows being the student. If one student wants to be with another one, they have a cost of 0 and if someone doesn't want to be with someone else they get a cost of 1. My only question now would be which cost  do they get when they have no preference set toward the other person, 0 as well ?